# Mobile Unity Shader - how to work with on/off boolean

Tags: unity, shaders

How do you set a boolean for a shader? 
How do you write a conditional or assign a boolean in a shader?

So, it seems that shaders do not take booleans... so I tried assigning the float to 0 or 1 `ren.material.SetFloat("_ZWriteVal", 1f);`, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
 Shader "ZTestLess"
{

 Properties {
_Color ("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
[Toggle(Z_WRITE_VAL)] 
_ZWriteVal("Z Write Val", Float) = 0
}

SubShader
 {
    Tags { "Queue" = "Background" }

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma shader_feature Z_WRITE_VAL

         #ifdef Z_WRITE_VAL
            ZWrite On
         #else 
            ZWrite Off

           ZTest Less
            Color [_Color]
            Lighting Off 

         ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change this toggle in script at runtime? [That's not possible when using preprocessor directives](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/183164/39518).  If that's not what you're trying to do, have you tried using an `Int` instead?

Comment: I' trying to switch to/from Zwrite On to Zwrite Off at runtime to create a "dynamic material"

Comment: You can't do that, as explained at the link above. But you can swap between two different materials, one you've configured with ZWrite on, and the other with ZWrite off.