# How to programmatically activate the Glow option in a Text Mesh Pro font

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

I can activate the Glow setting for a Font in Text Mesh Pro by checking the Glow checkbox:

[image]

Is there a way I can programmatically do the same thing?  I looked in the corresponding shader, and found what I think is the name of the variable: GLOW_ON.  But when I tried to set that variable to 1 using Material Set Float and Set Int, neither one worked.  Either I have the wrong variable name, or I'm not setting it the proper way.

Any suggestions on how to programmatically activate the Glow option in a Text Mesh Pro font?

Comment: Also just tried Set Integer, but that didn't work either.

Comment: See also: [Unity toggleable shader property misbehaves when set by code?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/183164/39518)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a shader variant using `#pragma shader_feature`, See [SL-MultipleProgramVariants](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-MultipleProgramVariants.html).

"*TextMeshPro/Mobile/Distance Field*":

```
#pragma shader_feature __ GLOW_ON
...
#ifdef GLOW_ON
...
#endif
```

So use [Material.EnableKeyword](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.EnableKeyword.html)(and [DisableKeyword](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.DisableKeyword.html)) in C# code:

```
material.EnableKeyword("GLOW_ON");
material.DisableKeyword("GLOW_ON");
```

And,

> The version of this function that takes a string as a parameter is slower than the version that takes a LocalKeyword. If you call this function more than once, it is best practice to create a LocalKeyword struct, cache it, and use that.

Comment: Instead of typing out the string, you can also get it from `TMPro.ShaderUtilities.Keyword_Glow`

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly. Thank you!!